# How to get real address of function in VC++

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dllimport

I am learning about Win32API .
My Program  have two function . 
I try use debug mode in VC++ . I set a break point when call dumy function

```
void CALLBACK Dummy(){

    printf("\n Hello Dummy Func!");
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

      (breakPoint) Dummy();
}
```

when I call dumy() function . Program jump to a address 012110D7 as flow code

```
Dummy:
012110D7  jmp         Dummy(12113A0h)
```

while real address of dummy function is 12113A0h
My Question is How to get real address of Dummy function is 12113A0h
The Problem resolved when i run in release Mode.
This is first time i join StackOver flow . I hope every body help me. Thank you !! BUZZ

Answer (score 5):

This jmp instruction is inserted by the linker to support Edit + Continue in the Debug configuration.  Which allows editing and compiling your code while you debug.  The extra indirection through the jmp instruction allows generating a different version of the function, the jmp destination is altered to make the changes effective.

Turn Edit and Continue off with Project + Properties, Linker, General, Enabled Incremental Linking = No.

Comment: thank you :X . When i add static modifier then my problem resolved